# Freezes screen with dispatch

Tags: ios, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I use this code and it freezes screen. Why this happens?

```
__block double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    if ([self loginTypeIsUser])
    {
        [self getVideoPlayLinksForEntity:wallpostEntity];
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you describe what `getVideoPlayLinksForEntity` and `loginTypeIsUser` are doing?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you're locking the main thread. You should not `dispatch_get_main_queue()` but do it on the background.

Try:

`dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)`

or

`dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)`

Comment: if I do this queues in class inherited from NSObject, I can not create queue like queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.queue.request", nil); here. Am I right? So how to solve it?

Comment: Did you try to change dispatch_get_main_queue() for dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0) already?

Comment: @user3587674 Yes, you cans use your own custom background queue if you want. Or as Winston suggests, you can use one of the global queues. You can use whatever queue you want (assuming, of course, these methods do not need to run on the main queue ... e.g., all UI stuff should happen on the main queue). And just so future readers aren't mislead, it's not the fact that you're doing `dispatch_after` on the main queue (as that's fine, and non-blocking), but rather that once it fires, that `getVideoPlayLinksForEntity` or `loginTypeIsUser` is presumably doing something slow synchronously.